# Swift clean code with nested functions

Tags: swift, coding-style, nested-function

I'm a not happy with my current code style when using nested functions.

When do I use nested functions?

Lets say I have a function with one argument. The argument needs to be validated. I will use guard to to it. Now you can split your tasks within the method in smaller methods. So that every method has a maximum of n lines. You could make the extracted methods private, but that would be a bigger scope then I need. Because the methods are only used within that method. The smallest scope I could use would be a nested function.

But in my opinion the code gets dirty when having nested functions.

The following example shows my current code style.

```
private func myFunction(iterationCount: Int) {
    func nestedOne() {

    }
    func nestedTwo(param: Int) {

    }
    guard iterationCount > 0 else {
        return
    }
    for i in 0 ..< iterationCount {
        nestedOne()
        nestedTwo(i)
    }
}
```

What do you think about that code style?

**EDIT:**

---

This is the real-world example. That should be enough information. Every method it-self has just a few lines of code. But all together have a lot lines of code. But making them private would make them accessible to the class. And the methods will never be used by another method.

```
private func rotateToPoint(newCenterPoint centerPoint: CGPoint, withDuration duration: Double) -> Bool {
    func createAnimation(/*n params here*/) -> CAKeyframeAnimation {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        // Create a CAKeyframeAnimation with the given path, duration etc.
        //
        //
        // Method has about this numer of lines.
        //
        //
        return animation
    }
    func createPathForRotation(/*n params here*/) -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        // Calculcate the path to move a view with an rotating second view.
        //
        //
        // Method has about this number of lines.
        //
        //
        //
        return path
    }
    func completionAction(/*n params here*/) {
        // Update state etc.
        //
        // Method has about this number of lines.
        //
        //
    }
    guard true /* check here */ else {
        return false
    }
    // Some variables and method calls here.
    //
    // Method has about this number of lines.
    //
    //
    //
    //
    return true
}
```

Comment: Please describe what `nestedOne` and `nestedTwo` should do so I can provide a contextual answer.

Comment: added an real-world example

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have written there - or right. People have different ideas about what is clean and what is dirty. Hard rules like " every method has a maximum of n lines" are bad, there's always a need for flexibility.

Comment: Lets assume you want your code to be fully testable - then how you test nested functions? They are unreachable by concept.
There are also lambdas or unnamed functions executed immediately (in other languages, don't know about swift but assume there is sth like that) etc. so why not ask question "is there any func that doesn't have to be tested"? If so, then why it's not statement? Is it even possible to have such func if you want your code to be fully testable?

Answer (score 0):

Since your inner functions are used to create values, you could use closures to initialize and set your variables/constants.

```
private func rotateToPoint(newCenterPoint centerPoint: CGPoint, withDuration duration: Double) -> Bool {
    guard true /* check here */ else {
        return false
    }

    let animation : CAKeyframeAnimation = {
        let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        // set animation properties...
        return animation
    }()

    let path: UIBezierPath = {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        // seth path properties
        return path
    }()

    let completion: (String)->() =  { (word:String)->() in

    } // <- IMPORTANT! no parenthesis here

    // just use animation, path and completion

    return true
}
```

Now as you wanted

1. variables/constants declared inside the closures are not visibile by `rotateToPoint`
2. variable/constants created with the closures are not visibile outside of `rotateToPoint`
3. IMHO the code is cleaner